# Sending Kubernetes Fluentd Logs to Elasticsearch Cluster On Another Server

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd

I have a k8s application that i have setup to log to fluentd.
On a standalone server, I have elasticsearch/kibana/fluentd running and listening on port 24224.

However, i cannot get logs to send from the Kubernetes application to my server. Is it possible to do this? Any suggestions on best process?

I used documentation from fluentd to setup generic out-forward and in-forward  plugins but its still not working. Any help is appreciated

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fluentd
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluentd
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
```

Daemonset i'm using:
https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/blob/master/fluentd-daemonset-forward.yaml

configMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd
data:
  app.conf: |
    <match pattern>
      @type forward
      send_timeout 60s
      recover_wait 10s
      hard_timeout 60s
     <server>
        name central_server
        host [hostname]
        port 24224
        weight 60
      </server>
      compress gzip
      append true
      <buffer tag,time>
        timekey 1d
        timekey_use_utc true
        timekey_wait 10m
      </buffer>
    </match>
```

Comment: You have provided a too generic description of your problem ****i cannot get logs to send from the Kubernetes application to my server****, which could be due to any reason.

Comment: You don't want to your app to send directly to fluentd, you want to log to stdout and have a k8s daemonset that runs fluentd on every node to forward.

Comment: I will add my current config @P....